# Changing path to parent directory of active working folder

Tags: vba, directory, parent

I have a code that is list files in directory. how can I address code to look into parent directory of current workbook directory? i want it to be independent wherever I place it. 
(first code addressing to the second one to read file from)
Thanks.

```
....
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      ShowPDFs "C:\Test\Working\", ws
        ws.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
------------------------------
Private Sub ShowPDFs(ByRef fsoPath.......
```

Comment: Try using `InStrRev` function to find `\` from right and convert your string to the parent path.

Comment: The parent directory of a directory is easily obtainable by using `\..`.  E.g. if you had a variable (let's call it `myPath`) that contains the path `"C:\Test\Working"`, then `myPath & "\.."` would be `"C:\Test\Working\.."` which is equivalent to `"C:\Test"`.  (But I don't understand the question enough to work out what you are trying to do with that fact.)

Comment: @YowE3K: At the moment when I move my workbook into different directory or pc station, I need to re-map this address to suit my content folder. I want it read parent directory of physical workbook drive. In other words, ir remap by code. It might be sometimes drive c or d or even network. Hope it it make sense.  Cheers

Comment: So, if this was Excel VBA code, you want to use `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\.."` as the directory to use?  So that if the workbook was `"X:\dir1\dir2\dir3\myBook.xlsm"` it would look in the `"X:\dir1\dir2"` directory.

Comment: `createobject("scripting.filesystemobject").getfolder(thisworkbook.Path).parentfolder.path`

Comment: @TimWilliams Easier just to append `"\.."` ;)  (But you can tell that I am showing my age :D)

Comment: Agreed - just thinking out loud. (agreed easier not agreed age...)

Answer (score 0):

Just check that the file is not at root level:

```
....
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        ShowPDFs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\..", ws

        ws.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
------------------------------
Private Sub ShowPDFs(ByRef fsoPath.......
```

Comment: I updated the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46868957/4914662) as well

Comment: Setting `par` to be **just** `"\.."` will mean that it is pointing to the root directory of the current drive.  I think you want to use `par = par & IIf(Len(par) > 2, "\..", "")` so that it either points to the parent directory of the directory containing the workbook (i.e. `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\.."`) or to the `"C:"` or `"\\"`. But if `ThisWorkbook.Path` was just `"C:"`, then you can still use `"C:\.."` OK, so you may as well replace the whole line with `par = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\.."`.  (I don't think `ThisWorkbook.Path` could ever just be `"\\"` so there's not much point catering for it.)

Comment: @YowE3K - good point - I updated the `par & "\.."` part. I'll check tomorrow on a network path and if `ThisWorkbook.Path` cannot be `"\\"` I'll just remove all `"par"` lines (but I think it I used it before to determine if I'm dealing with a network location)

Comment: I can't imagine a UNC path that doesn't include a computer name (i.e. I don't think a filename of `\\myworkbook.xlsm` would be possible) but there might be problems if the UNC was something like `\\mycomputer\myworkbook.xlsm` - that might confuse things if you try to look at the directory `\\mycomputer\..`.  I'll let you do some testing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you want:

**If your behavior is to open an excel window and then open your recent file, please note that you should not forget to add change Drive and then change Directory into your VBA code.**

Cause the Excel always start with the default Directory even it's just open your recent file !

Then, these should be help.

**Solution A:** *You don't need to get parent directory to do anything else.*

```
Dim ThisWorkbookPath As String
Dim ThisWorkbookPathParts As Variant

ThisWorkbookPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
ThisWorkbookPathParts = Split(ThisWorkbookPath, _
                        Application.PathSeparator)

ChDrive ThisWorkbookPathParts(LBound(ThisWorkbookPathParts))
ChDir ThisWorkbookPath
```

**Solution B:** *You may need to get parent directory to do things else.*

```
Dim ParentPath As String: ParentPath = "\"
Dim ThisWorkbookPath As String
Dim ThisWorkbookPathParts, Part As Variant
Dim Count, Parts As Long

ThisWorkbookPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
ThisWorkbookPathParts = Split(ThisWorkbookPath, _
                        Application.PathSeparator)

Parts = UBound(ThisWorkbookPathParts)
Count = 0
For Each Part In ThisWorkbookPathParts
    If Count > 0 Then
        ParentPath = ParentPath & Part & "\"
    End If
    Count = Count + 1
    If Count = Parts Then Exit For
Next

MsgBox "File-Drive = " & ThisWorkbookPathParts _
       (LBound(ThisWorkbookPathParts))
MsgBox "Parent-Path = " & ParentPath
```